# How does 2D kriging interpolation work?

Tags: statistics, interpolation, data-analysis, covariance

I have a grid of points

Example

```
   x         80     82.5     85    87.5    90

 y 5        0.5      1.6     1.7    1.7    2.3

   2.5      1.6      1.7     1.8    2.1    2.7

   0        2.4      2.3     2.6    3.0    3.8
```

and I want to be able to find any point for example point (81,4)

What would I need to do to find this point using 2D [kriging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging)?
Could someone show me the mathematical steps to reach my value.

Here is an Example of the Calculus behind 1d kriging

http://www.climateneeds.umd.edu/pdf/EfficientKrigingforReal-Time.pdf

Comment: Is the header for the fourth column supposed to be $87.5$?

Comment: The answer would amount to explain the whole kringing procedure (of which there are many variations), the question looks to broad to me. If you understand 1D kriging, you should explain what are your doubts for generalizing it; if you don't, then you should just read the linked material.

Comment: @leonbloy , I did see that they have multiple versions of Kriging but I want to see how ordinary kriging is done, which as far as my knowledge goes, only one type of ordinary kriging exists